# Encoding node ID

Tags: dac, canopen

I am looking for a best way to encode CANOpen node ID on the PCB. At the moment it is hardcoded in the firmware. The requirements are 1) 8 or 16 values, 2) small footprint, and 3) low cost.
Note that the ID will be set once during production and almost never changed afterwards. However it would be nice to be able to change it quickly during software development.

Most important restriction is that I can spare just one MCU pin for this feature, so it seems the only option is to use ADC input and somehow encode ID as voltage on this pin. Here are some potential solutions I am looking at:

Solution 1:

Add permanent pull-down (10k) and pads for hand-soldered encoding resistor (0.35 - 97k). This satisfies all 3 requirements nicely and has the smallest possible footprint. Unfortunately, it does not provide nice-to-have quick change capability. It also adds soldering step to the assembly process.

Solution 2:

Add rotary switch (e.g. this [SP10T](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/c-k/RW-1106-NS-RT/2747157)) and serial resistor ladder. This delivers everything, except for small footprint, which is an important requirement. It is also quite cumbersome.

Solution 3:

Add hex coded switch (e.g. [SH-7050TA](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/nidec-copal-electronics/SH-7050TA/2057872)) and connect it to MSB inputs of DAC chip (e.g. [MAX5102](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/maxim-integrated/MAX5102BEUE-T/1781777)). This seems to be compact enough (7.5 x 7.3 mm switch + 6.5 x 5.0 mm DAC) and delivers all the desired functionality. But at $5.33 per board it is also most expensive solution.

There is also a variant of this using discrete R-2R ladder and small OpAmp.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you thought about solder bridges? Maybe just one for debug/developement use, to override some setting? Which MCU you are using, maybe there's EEPROM or something you can configure some values.

Comment: +1 for using EEPROM if you have it.

Comment: Even just Flash with some IAP procedure ? I use the last bytes of my dspic to memorize some calibration offset in production. You only need a read/program/write procedure not to lose it if the MCU is flashed again after production.

Comment: @Justme Using [STM32L4Q5](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32l4q5cg.html). No EEPROM on this one, but I do have external QSPI FLASH chip on board. Could be interesting option. The reason I did not think of it is because our DFU process uses node IDs to remotely install/update correct firmware packages. So there is a bit of chicken/egg situation here.